# Laravel5 link_to_action doesn't work when trying to delete an article

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a basic blog with Laravel, then when I tried to add the delete method to the 'show' view, but after I confirm the deletion, nothing happens further.

The route looks like:

```
DELETE      | articles/{articles}   | articles.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@destroy
```

My code looks the following:

In the view called 'show', where the selected article is displayed, below I wanted to add the link like:

```
{!! link_to_action('ArticlesController@destroy', 'Delete Article', $article->id, ['method'=>'DELETE', 'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'onClick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")']); !!}
```

In the ArticlesController, I've written the 'destroy' function just like:

```
    public function destroy(Article $article) {

        $article->delete();

        return redirect('articles')->with([
            'flash_message' => 'Article successfully deleted.',
            'flash_message_important' => 'true',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `DELETE | articles/{articles}` be `DELETE | articles/{article}` ?

Comment: @Matey AFAIK `articles/{articles}` becomes `articles/{article}` in Laravel 5.3. [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) under Routing: 
In Laravel 5.3, all resource route parameters are singularized by default. So, the same call to  Route::resource would register the following URI:

`/photos/{photo}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `link_to_action` which is not included with Laravel 5. See [this post](http://laravel.io/forum/02-04-2015-laravel-5-error-link-to-route?page=1#reply-20702).

To use the link_to_route helper you need to pull the `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` package.

Comment: Actually I've learnt the method from the Laravel 5 Fundamentals training, so I wouldn't have expected this to happen.  I've replaced the link with a 'form' element with 'DELETE' method, so now everything works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sklrboy I suggest you post this as an answer to your question in case someone run into the same problem as you in the future.

Comment: I vote this answer since it solvers OP problem and informs others. I believe this should be marked as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$article->id` in the delete request parameters. And you are trying to retrieve `Article` object in `destroy()` method. That is wrong.

Modify your destroy method as following

```
    public function destroy($article_id)
  {
    Article $article = Article::find($article_id);
    if ($article != null) {
        $article->delete();
        return redirect('articles')->with([
            'flash_message' => 'Article successfully deleted.',
            'flash_message_important' => 'true',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And it will work.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you checking if article is null? If the article wasn't found, this would've thrown an exception with `findOrFail`

Comment: You've been writing Java recently?  I don't think PHP will like `Article $article = Article::findorFail($article_id);`.  Laravel also does implicit route binding so that if an ID was passed, Laravel will actually pass in an instance of `Article` into this function even though it looks like it will be receiving an ID.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @ChrisForrence: You are right. Modified my answer. @user3158900: Yeah, working on android app. But laravel do have `findorFail`. Please refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: ...and than he changed `Article $article = Article::findorFail($article_id);` to `Article $article = Article::find($article_id);` instead of `$article = Article::findorFail($article_id);` (even if he wanted to use that ugly construction)... Nitesh, this is not the first time we met, you are a remarkable person! :)

Comment: I don't get it why would you take just the $article->id argument into the function, but then inside would call the whole Article $article class?? Anyways, in the update method I just pass the $article->id too, but in the function I take Article $article as an argument, and it works perfectly there... The problem might seriously be, that in form way it works, but in link_to_action it doesnt yet at Laravel 5.0.

Comment: @sklrboy yeah, thats how form-model binding works. you need a form to do that.